# How do I bind hgsubversion to a newer version of SVN?

Tags: svn, mercurial

I need to convert an SVN repository to Mercurial.

I've tried this a number of ways, all of which have failed. I'm currently trying to use hgsubversion.

The problem I'm encountering is a SVN version mismatch. The repository was made with 1.8.9, but hgsubversion is bundled with SVN version 1.6.16. This leads to a file system mismatch, and hgsubversion can't read the repo.

I've installed the latest version of SVN, 1.8.16, but I can't figure out how to make hgsubversion use the newer version.

I've downloaded the SWIG bindings, but they seem to point to the old version packaged with hgsubversion, not the new one I installed.

I looked at installing subvertpy, but I'm on Windows, and it looks like that's going to be quite an ordeal. There isn't much in the way of documentation, so it's not clear if I could point it at the newer SVN version anyway.

I downloaded the latest versions of TortoiseHg, HgSubversion, the SWIG bindings, and Subversion, all within the past two days. I uninstalled the previous versions I had of Tortoise and Subversion, and installed these new ones.

Here's the output from the TortoiseHg Workbench for the versions:

> % hg version --svn
>   Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.9)
>   (see https://mercurial-scm.org for more information)
>
> Copyright (C) 2005-2016 Matt Mackall and others
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> hgsubversion: 1.8.6
>   Subversion: 1.6.16
>   bindings: SWIG
>   [command completed successfully Thu Aug 25 16:41:28 2016]
>
> % svn --version
>   svn, version 1.8.9 (r1591380)
>      compiled May  6 2014, 20:28:35 on x86-microsoft-windows

I'm using local URLs with the 'file:///' protocol, as we don't have an SVN server. This is the main reason we are trying to get this repo converted to Hg. Here's the output from trying to clone the repo:

> % hg clone file:///C:/Code/Iris/SvnRepo file:///C:/Code/Iris/ConvertedToHg
>   abort: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
>   Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/Code/Iris/SvnRepo'
>   Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'
>   [command returned code 255 Thu Aug 25 16:46:44 2016]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

1. You have old, outdated binding (or ancient version of Mercurial?). From my THG installation:

> ```
> >hg version --svn
> ...
> hgsubversion: 8937f19586fe
> Subversion: 1.7.5
> bindings: SWIG
> ```

2. Version of SVN in binding play game **only** if you'll access SVN-repository with `file:///` protocol, with any **real network layer** in the middle it's irrelevant (I always run svnserve for local repos in such cases)

Comment: I have the most recent versions of TortoiseHG, Mercurial, and the SWIG bindings, all downloaded in the past two days. The grammar on point 2 doesn't really make sense to me, but I am using the file protocol, as we don't have an SVN server, which is the main reason we're converting this repo to Mercurial.

Comment: @DCShannon - and *check carefully* used `svnbinding` extension